# Fastest way to get local time in unix

Tags: c++, unix, gmt

I am investigating logging performance on unix system. Thing is I found that the most expensive operation is obtaining date.

Currently I am getting time like this -

```
timeb currTime;
struct tm localTime;
ftime( &currTime )
localtime_r(&currTime.time, &localTime);
```

I changed it to

```
struct timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL); 
time_t curtime = tv.tv_sec;
struct tm localTime = *(localtime(&curtime));
```

and did not see any performance improvement. So I am wondering maybe this is not the fastest way to get local time on unix systems?

Please, share you thoughts about that.

Thanks on advance.

Comment: What are your performance requirements?

Comment: as best as is can be :)

Comment: I also should be able to format retrieved date like YYYY.MM.DD HH.MM.SS.mSmS

Comment: Don't format it in the hot thread. Just store the timestamp, and do the log formatting offline.

Comment: Actually, I have an object which is passed by reference to function which is obtaining time and afterwards logger is going on working with that object. I think the huge part of slowliness is cases because of that object. But thing is I cant change an interface of function, because a lot of code is dependent on that function.

Comment: You need to qualify your performance requirements better. What level of performance do you *need*? We all want O(0) but we're never going to get it.

Comment: Don't work with local time. Use UTC for all internal times, and only convert to local for presentation to the user.

Answer (score 1):

gettimeofday gives you the UTC time very quickly.   Converting to local time is not so quick.

Defer converting that to local time until you are off the performance critical path.

Also you can cache the UTC to local time conversion factor once a day to speed up the conversion to local time, although this is not perfect it is probably good enough for logging purposes.